# Java script html using dropdown value as part of a ur in buttons on click event

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have a form that uses the selected item in a drop down, and is supposed to go to a specific ur in the button click event... Here is what I'm looking for..

Button on click event is 
www.something.com/something=$variable

Where $variable is what the user selects in the drop down list.

I can't just use the simple get method because I have other buttons on the form that open a specific window as well, but with PERL variables.

Can anyone tell me how to take the value in the Drop down list and insert it into the end of that url I provided? Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: this is fairly trivial and easy to research, what have you tried?

Comment: I have two buttons on a form. When the button is clicked, the new window must pop up and the original form must not refresh or go to a new page.. so I have used the On Click event for both buttons.

Comment: I have a looked at how to take the value of the drop down and assign it as the value of the button.. but i'm not sure how to make the selected item text be passed into a variable that can be added to the literal "on click='html://website.com/variable=$variable'"

I'm confused with how to do this..